# Why is my Linux system repeating every command that I type?

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm using a Ubuntu Linux system, and every command I enter is displayed on the next line, followed by the output of the command. For example:

```
root@dpkube165:~# ls
ls  <--- why is this here?
Desktop  Documents  Downloads 

root@dpkube165:~# date
date  <--- or this?
Mon Mar 19 11:24:59 EDT 2018

root@dpkube165:~# echo "Hello, world!"
echo "Hello, world!" <--- or this?
Hello, world!
```

I thought it might have to do with the prompt, which is as follows (PS1):

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
```

but reviewing online guides to prompt escape sequences didn't turn up anything obvious.

Comment: You also appear to be logged in as root.  Don't do that!

Comment: Yes, I know to avoid root most of the time. This is on a VM in a throwaway testing environment where root is required.

Comment: @TobySpeight this is hackneyed, rote advice.

Comment: @TobySpeight Seriously, don't push that as an absolute rule. Tell me, what's wrong with using `sudo -i` to run a series of root-level commands? Especially when I'm debugging something?

Comment: I didn't expect to have to explain something that obvious to users of [unix.se]!  I thought everybody understood the general advice to use the root account for things that require the privilege, and ordinary user accounts for things that don't.  If not, there's plenty of other resources to learn from, and I don't have the time for that kind of spoonfeeding right now.

Comment: @TobySpeight if you don’t have time to explain, don’t give blanket “advice” which is often unhelpful.

Comment: @Tim, the advice was given, understood and acknowledged - what's the problem?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

It looks like you have `-v` set (something is running `set -v`).

To reverse this, run `set +v`.

> ```
> set [--abefhkmnptuvxBCEHPT] [-o option-name] [arg ...]
> set [+abefhkmnptuvxBCEHPT] [+o option-name] [arg ...]
>        Without  options, the name and value of each shell variable are displayed in a
>        format that can be reused as input for setting or resetting the currently-set
>        variables. Read-only variables cannot be reset. In posix mode, only shell
>        variables are  listed. The output is sorted according to the current locale.
>        When options are specified, they set or unset shell attributes. Any arguments
>        remaining after option processing are treated as values for the positional
>        parameters and are assigned, in order, to $1, $2, ...  $n.  Options, if
>        specified, have the following meanings:
>
> [...]
>
> -v      Print shell input lines as they are read.
> ```

See the [`bash` manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) (under the "*Shell Builtin Commands*" section) for more information on the `set` built-in command.

Alternatively run `help set` from within `bash` for more direct access to the help text.

Comment: Yep! As a slightly more convenient alternative to digging through `man bash`, you can also `help set`.

Comment: You legend... The time I've spent scrolling in the `bash` manpage... thanks!

Comment: My very first command after starting a bash that I don't own is always `set -o vi`.  Mistype that as `set -ovi` and you'll get the above behaviour.

Comment: as to the Why - I would suspect there's a script being sourced (i.e. ". ./srciptname" instead of just "./scriptname") which then exits before it unsets -v, i.e. at end it should "set +v"

Comment: BTW, I find `set -x` more useful for logging, or debugging of things other than control-flow, because it expands variables to show what commands are *actually* being run, e.g. `echo foo` instead of `echo $my_string`

Comment: @GuntramBlohm You just described *exactly* what happened!

Answer (score 11):

At least on Bash 4.3, this command has a similar effect to `set -v`:

```
trap 'echo "$BASH_COMMAND"' DEBUG
```

To check if this affects you, run

```
trap -p DEBUG
```

To unset it, run

```
trap - DEBUG
```